# Is the a way to integrate utam with Playwright?

Tags: utam

I am wondering if there is a way to combine using UTAM with salesforce-object and Playwright? If so, can someone provide an example configuration with a simple example test script?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Have you checked the [Playwright Discord channel](https://discord.com/servers/playwright-807756831384403968)?